# VBA - SQL with optional joins

Tags: vba, excel

I have a combolist where I can select multiple values, but if I leave them all blank then I want to exclude that portion from the query. Here is the current logic I'm using

```
        If ModeCat_ID = "" Then
            Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [ModeCat_T]")
        Else
             Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [ModeCat_T] WHERE [ModeCat_ID] = '" & ModeCat_ID & "'")
        End If
```

My question is, is this the best way to go about this? I'm building a form that has a few more options so I'd rather not have a bunch of tested Ifs to check these form controls.

Second question is, if it's a combo box that can select multiples.. how would I set that up for an SQL IN statement? ie

```
IN ('1','2','3')
```

Thanks!

EDIT

```
 Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [ModeCat_T]")
```

Comment: If you have working code, I'd recommend you take the whole procedure (heck, even the whole module) over to [codereview.se], where "is this the best/cleanest way of doing this?" is precisely what the entire site addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I normally do it:

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "set nocount on; "
strSQL = strSQL & "select * "
strSQL = strSQL & "from [ModeCat_T] "
strSQL = strSQL & "     where 1 = 1  "
'*******************************************************
'*  Adding the other where restrictions as necessary
'*******************************************************
If Trim(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value2) <> vbNullString Then
    strSQL = strSQL & "     and [ModeCat_ID] = '" & Sheet1.Range("B7").Value2 & "' "
End If
If Trim(Sheet1.Range("B8").Value2) <> vbNullString Then
    strSQL = strSQL & "     and [ModeCat_Color] = '" & Sheet1.Range("B8").Value2 & "' "
End If
If Trim(Sheet1.Range("B9").Value2) <> vbNullString Then
    strSQL = strSQL & "     and [ModeCat_Size] = '" & Sheet1.Range("B9").Value2 & "' "
End If

Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
```

Following the continued discussion about "Filters" where you can select possibly many different items from a `ListBox` the following code might be able to help with that:

```
Dim strFilter As String
Dim lngItem As Long

For lngItem = 0 To UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(lngItem) = True Then
        If strFilter <> vbNullString Then strFilter = strFilter & ", "
        strFilter = strFilter & "'"
        strFilter = strFilter & UserForm1.ListBox1.List(lngItem, 1)
        strFilter = strFilter & "'"
    End If
Next lngItem

If strFilter <> vbNullString Then
    strSQL = strSQL & "and [ModeCat_Form] in (" & strFilter & ") "
End If
```

Basically, it is checking which items from the list have been selected and puts them into a string (wrapped in ' and separated by a comma). Afterwards the code checks if anything made it into the "Filter String". If the filter is not empty then it should be used. BTW: it does not matter if the string contains one or many items. So, this is also permissible:

```
   AND [ModeCat_Shape] in ('Oval')
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, how would I apply the strSQL appendix to my code, included the connect string in my original post in EDIT. I need to change to using htis appendix since my SQL query is super long and is nearly 300 lines long lol.

Comment: Never mind I see it as the last statement in your code. Perfect!

Comment: Wouldn't want to be the person administering this! I would suggest looping through the range checking for null values and a reference next to it for the field name.

Comment: @Gareth: Yes, of course, you can make it more dynamic by storing on a sheet in (as an example) column A the SQL name and in column B the search criteria and then loop through this range. I just never did it because of bad experiences in the past. Users kept fiddling around with column A and got errors back. SQL injection comes to mind... So, I like to keep it in the VBA code and do the checking there. More work but slightly more hidden and less prone to user-hazards.

Comment: @JeffBeagley: Don't worry. String variables can potentially store up to 2 billion characters according to this article from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28v=vs.60%29.aspx I myself have even used string variables on occasion to move small files as a stream to an SQL server. So, you should be save to have 300+ lines in there.

Comment: Good to know! This is my first experience using VBA coming from PHP, so I write all my SQL out as to take up as many rows as possible, so when I copy/pasted that into VBA I had a moment of panic lol.

Comment: @JeffBeagley: I just appended the requested list box to allow for selecting multiple items. Let me know if this is what you've been looking for.

Comment: @Ralph Okay I believe it's nearly working - Currently it's selecting my first column which is just a description, where I want to use the actual ID. 

Looking at my code that populates the form_mode listbox is
`i = 0
        With Main_Window.form_mode
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem
            .List(i, 0) = rst![Mode]
            .List(i, 1) = rst![ID]
            i = i + 1
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop Until rst.EOF`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91759/discussion-between-ralph-and-jeff-beagley).

Comment: Got it to work using the following

`Dim strFilter As String
        Dim i As Integer
        
        For i = 0 To Main_Window.form_mode.ListCount - 1
            If Main_Window.form_mode.Selected(i) Then
                If strFilter <> vbNullString Then strFilter = strFilter & ", "
                strFilter = strFilter & "'"
                strFilter = strFilter & Main_Window.form_mode.List(i, 1)
                strFilter = strFilter & "'"
            End If
        Next i`

Comment: So now I need to apply this logic to a Textbox.. I am copy/pasting multiple values into the text box then I need to split those values up, and place them inside an SQL IN statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

I felt I should expand my comment the @Ralphs answer with a more maintainable solution.

As you're using a `ComboBox` and by the sound of it your wanting the user to be able to select multiple columns, use a `ListBox` instead. I would hide the reference to the field name in the first column of the `ListBox` by setting it's column width to 0. Then in the next column, you could add the actual filter in there.

Once this is done, you can iterate through the selected items to apply the filters like so:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        strSQL = " AND " & ListBox1.Column(0, i) & " = '" & ListBox1.Column(1, i) & "'"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I did indeed change it to a listbox, but the options would need to be in an IN statement and not AND.

AND [s].[ModeCat_ID] IN ('6','7','8','9')

Comment: @JeffBeagley so the values would all be filtering against the same field?

Comment: Correct. It'd basically be an OR

Comment: @JeffBeagley `OR` and `IN` are two different things

Comment: So how would I make a clause that is if null, then exclude that in the WHERE statement, but if it were 1, have it equal that value, but if more than 1, do an in statement and loop the results